# Кириллица при чтении из QFile и запись в QString с последующим выведением в Label QtCreator 5.13

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, кириллица

В моей программе должна читаться строка на русском языке из файла `QFile`, записываться в `QString`, и затем выводиться в `QLabel`. Но при выведении в `QLabel` выводится вместо букв эти символы: `�`. При введении в файл слов на английском данной проблемы нет.

Comment: Смотрите кодировку файла, возможно там `cp1251`, или `utf8`, А дальше при чтении используйте статические функции из `QString`, все они начинаются на `QString::from*`

Comment: если 1251, то надо `QTextCodec` применять